# Datepicker in fluid typo3

Tags: fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I am working with a typo3 extbase extension and I got stuck with this particular point.
Can we have a typo3 fluid equivalent for

```
<input type="date" />
```

I need to have a date picker in my extension. Is it possible with typo3 fluid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for 10.4:

Add the datepicker module to your extension (ext_localconf.php):

```
if(TYPO3_MODE === 'BE'){
    $pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
    $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/DateTimePicker');
}
```

Then you can use this Fluid in a TYPO3 Backend Module:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" id="my-unique-identifier"
          class="t3js-datetimepicker form-control t3js-clearable hasDefaultValue" data-date-type="date"
          data-formengine-input-name="my-input-field-name"
          data-formengine-input-initialized="true">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
       <label class="btn btn-default" for="my-unique-identifier">
          <core:icon identifier="actions-calendar-alternative" size="small" />
       </label>
   </span>
</div>
```

The value `data-date-type` can be set to "date" or "datetime".

Don't forget to add core namespace to your Fluid template for the Icon API:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
  xmlns:core="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Core/ViewHelpers"
  data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo3 8.7 lets you utilise jquery datepicker.

First, add the datepicker module to your extension (ext_localconf.php):

```
//If you want to use it in the BE, include the If line
if(TYPO3_MODE === 'BE'){
    $pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
    $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/DateTimePicker','function() { initScript(); }');
}
```

...then you can use this fluid textfield to initiate the datepicker:

```
<f:form.textfield type="datetime" property="dateexample" id="dateexample" class="form-control t3js-datetimepicker t3js-clearable" data="{date-type:'datetime',date-offset:'0'}" value="{dateexample->f:format.date(format: 'd/m/Y')}" /><span class="input-group-btn"><label class="btn btn-default" for="dateexample"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></label></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you include an external library for this. For example, I have used jquery.datetimepicker, could you find it [here](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/tree/master/build) .

Modifiy your Typoscript setup.ts and add next lines

```
page {
 includeCSS {
    datetimepicker = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Public/Css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css
 }
 includeJS {
    JqueryUITimepicker = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Public/Js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js   
 }
}
```

In your Fluid Template use the next code:

```
<f:form.textfield type="text" id="datetimepicker" name="PublishDate" />
```

And in JS file include

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

The argument in the Controller will be `PublishDate` but receive it as string you have to convert with PHP in DateTime or the data type that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Fluid is not shipped with a date picker or required a specific one.

In fact you could use any HTML date picker.

Answer (score 0):

```
<f:form.textfield type="date" additionalAttributes="{min:'{f:format.date(date:\'now\',format:\'Y-m-d\')}'}"
                    name="{name}" value="{value}"
                    
/>
```

You need to use modern browsers. It should be work since TYPO3 6.2. ([docu](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-extbasefluid/6.2/en-us/Fluid/ViewHelper/Form/Textfield.html))

Answer (score 0):

For 11.5 with fluid:

Nearly identical solution Andrea posted, but that led to sending the date with the `@extension` field with the form.

So my solution:

Inject the `PageRenderer` in your controller and in the appropriate action do:
`$this->pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/DateTimePicker');`

In your template:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <f:form.textfield property="date" id="date" class="form-control t3js-datetimepicker t3js-clearable" data="{date-type: 'datetime', date-offset: 0}"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn"><label class="btn btn-default" for="date"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></label></span>
</div>
```